# ¿Es posible cambiar la forma en la que se ordenan las cosas en mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Hola mi duda es si puedo cambiar la forma en la que se ordena un array de msql en php al darle a un enlace, por ejemplo que al darle a precio alto la variable $resultado quede "selec * from  productos order by precio ASC" y lo demás... . Esto se puede hacer o debo crear otro div en que se ordene de ese modo y usar jquery para que al darle clic al  enlace(precio bajo) el display de #todo se ponga none.

```html
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Precio alto</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pricio bajo</a>
                    </div>
           
           
           
           
           <div class="row mb-5" id="todo">
                <?php
              
                include('php/conexion.php');
                $resultado= $conexion->query("select * from productos order by id DESC")or die($conexion->error);
                while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){


               ?>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                <div class="block-4 text-center border">
                  <figure class="block-4-image">
                    <a href="shop-single.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $fila['imagen'] ?>"  alt="Image placeholder" height="200" width="200"></a>
                  </figure>
                  <div class="block-4-text p-4">
                    <h3><a href="shop-single.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="mb-0"><?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?></p>
                    <p class="text-primary font-weight-bold">$<?php echo $fila['precio']; ?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php } ?>


            </div>
```

Comment: Puedes traer los datos en un orden por defecto y luego re-ordenarlos mediante acciones de algún elemento del DOM sin necesidad de buscarlos de nuevo en la base de datos. Para facilitar el trabajo, puedes traer los datos a algo así cómo un JSON y usar código Javascript para re-ordenarlos por una determinada clave del JSON. No es una buena idea volver una y otra vez al servidor a buscar los mismos datos, es mejor que los ordenes desde el cliente.

Comment: Por qué no es buena idea?

Comment: Porque significaría hacer cada vez una petición de red para traer los mismos datos. Poniendo un ejemplo de la vida real: imagina que tienes `N` cantidad de documentos en Australia y vives en los EEUU. Te piden que vayas a Australia a buscarlos y que los ordenes de X forma. Una 1ª vez viajas a Australia y traes los documentos a los EEUU. Bien bien, un viaje largo y costoso por unos documentos importantes. Ahora, ya en los EEUU te piden **los mismos documentos**, pero ordenados de otra forma. ¿Irías a Australia de nuevo a ordenar **los mismos documentos** o los ordenarías en los EEUU?

Comment: Con el ejemplo anterior quiero decir que una petición Ajax es costosa, para el cliente y para el servidor. Si para ordenar los mismos datos que ya tienes vas de nuevo al servidor, estarías sobrecargando el servidor y gastando recursos sin necesidad. Eso es particularmente grave en redes con poca capacidad de tráfico y conexiones concurrentes. Imagina millones de clientes haciendo lo mismo, yendo al servidor cada vez para ordenar unos datos que ya el servidor les ofreció. Imagina el costo en billetes a Australia. La empresa caerá en la quiebra tarde o temprano (tu sistema puede colapsar).

Comment: Sí te entendí, gracias. Osea que una vez hecho un select y teniendo los datos en $fila debo trabajar con esa variable el resto de veces?

Comment: No del todo. `$fila` sería una variable de PHP ¿no?, y PHP es el servidor, es Australia. En una 1ª instancia ordenarías los datos de la forma en que te los pidan inicialmente y los transportas al cliente (que es Javascript - los EEUU). Pero una vez en Javascript, si se necesita **ordenar esos mismos datos de otra forma**, no tienes que ir de nuevo a ordenar a `$fila` (en el servidor), sino que puedes tener en el cliente un objeto (JSON es lo mejor para esto) que sea fácilmente ordenable, por alguna clave. Pondrías funciones de escucha (en el cliente) para ordenar los datos según se te pida.

Comment: Otra cosa es que si son demasiados datos no conviene para nadie, ni para el servidor ni para el cliente. Imaginemos algo así como 1,000 o 20,000 o 1 millón de filas. En ese caso deberían pensar en algún tipo de paginación. Porque sea como sea, generalmente nadie trabaja en una sola página con miles de datos. Cuando los datos son muchos habría que paginar, mostrándolos por grupos. Pero ese es ya otro tema, no sé si es tu caso.

Comment: Te entiendo, me voy a poner a investigar sobre manejo de arrays en json. No son muchos datos, tengo un proyecto de escuela y tengo que hacer una página web http://musicdum.260mb.net/index.php . Estaba haciendo exactamente eso, pidiéndole al servidor que me ordenara los datos y luego me los enviara ordenados de ese modo y así para cada categoría, espero ya mañana que entienda bien json poder hacerlo de la forma correcta. Gracias